# Should i need to create Every time Newactivity for every List items Recycleview?

Tags: android

I have a recipe app which contains list of recipes like when i click burger it display burger recipe on new Activity.

So how to do this by creating single activity with different recipes for every list items?

I have store recipes on firebase.

Answer (score 0):

you can use fragment to show the recipe on same activity

Answer (score 0):

Prehaps showing some code could tell us what you already have?

I don't think you can do it all in one activity.(or at least it wouldn't look good). You can use a recycler view and each time an item on that view is clicked, you can create a new activity to display the details.

Or you can also use fragments and use a master-detail pane.

Answer (score 0):

make an activity which contains textview and imageviews according to your recipe items and pass the data to that activity on click of recyclerview through intent and then on that activity get that data from i,tent and set on the textview and imageviews

Comment: But please can someone tell me how to use fragment for this? For example. When i click an list item it will open a page with some information in textvuew but display different for each list item so how to do this using fragment?

Comment: if number of textview and imageview are same then no need for making different fragment just use my answer guide